# Browser extension for easier copy or search of selected text

Tags: web-browser, productivity

Is there a Firefox or Chrome add-on/extension that automatically pops up buttons (<kbd>Copy</kbd>, <kbd>Search</kbd>) when you select text from a web page? Thus allowing you to avoid the right click button as much as you can.

Something like this:

[image: Next to the highlighted text, two buttons "search" and "copy" are shown]

Comment: It doesn't currently have the *copy* operation, but [Selected Search](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/selected-search/) has the search functionality you desire.  It also looks trivial to add code to perform a *copy* operation.  If this works for you, I can expand it into an answer.

Comment: You were inspired by using Opera, right? If not, use Opera for this feature. I am actually looking for this in Firefox, too.

Comment: @MSC Sorry for late reply, I think Opera didn't have that feature when I posted this actually. But it's nice that they implemented the feature exactly like I imagined it.